# Barcode Reader using webcam for webapp

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, desktop, webcam, barcode

I'm looking for a barcode reader using a webcam for my shopping guide website with a redirection after scan to my search engine.
I found a lot of things for mobile apps, but nothing working good for the desktop web browsers.

This flex component doesn't work on my apple display webcam : http://www.renaun.com/flex2/BarcodeReader/BarcodeReader.html and I really need a tool who works with many desktop cams. (like the mac app http://www.delicious-monster.com/)

Wich technology can I use for that or do you have a little script to do that?

Thank you for your feedbacks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following:
[Flex barcode components](http://code.google.com/p/flexbars/source/browse/#svn/trunk/examples)

It may help.

Comment: Hi @michael, thx for your link but this flex component seems not working... :(